# How to move multiple lines so that they don't layer over each other

Tags: google-maps, math, svg, geometry, trigonometry

I am attempting to draw a number of lines on a map- basically, walking directions to subway stations. Many of these walking directions are the same for 50% or more of the journey (as you'd expect, coming from the same start point), so when I draw them, they draw on top of each other, obscuring each other- like so:

[image: Lines drawn on top of each other]

In this example, the red line is partly obscured by the yellow line- I would like to move the yellow e.g. at a 45 degree angle to place it parallel to the red line. I initially tried offsetting the X and Y coordinates by a few pixels, but any lines that aren't on 90 degree angles look wrong. I started playing around with calculating the degrees that a line is travelling on and to be honest I started to get lost- get the programming side of it, just not the geometry/trig/math of it.

Does anyone have some advice of what keywords I should even be looking for, or what paths I should be going down with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One trick is to stagger the lines when it overlaps. Here's 4 lines overlapping and staggered so that all lines are visible. Human eye is well trained to follow a color.

Example: http://jsbin.com/ovacar/1/edit

```
<svg>
  <path stroke="skyblue" stroke-width="4" stroke-dasharray="5,15" d="M0 20 l215 0" /> 
  <path stroke="cyan" stroke-width="4" stroke-dasharray="0,0,5,15" d="M5 20 l215 0" />
  <path stroke="pink" stroke-width="4" stroke-dasharray="0,5,5,10" d="M5 20 l215 0" />
  <path stroke="green" stroke-width="4" stroke-dasharray="0,10,5,5" d="M5 20 l215 0" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try just moving each corner on line 2 a couple of metre to the North East by adding a small fraction (try .00001 but experiment) to both lat and long values. This should give parallel lines when zoomed in.

You could also try reducing the opacity of the lines so they blend rather than overlay.